# Codeception: Test persists entity but ignores Gedmo blameable

Tags: codeception

Writing a functional test in Codeception (v2.5.5) for a Symfony (v4.2) project.

I'm testing submitting a form, which creates a new entity as expected, and redirects to another page.  I'm  looking to verify that the new entity exists and that the redirected page loads with a 200.

However, I noticed that the new entity is created, but the created_by and updated_by fields, which are typically set by @Gedmo\Blamable annotations on the entity, are not being set.

@Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create") does work, as the created_at and updated_at timestamps have been set.

Anyone run into this or have a suggestion of what to try?

Comment: Is the bundle enabled in test environment?

Comment: I suspected that was the case, but as far as I can tell, it is enabled.  There is a stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml at the config/packages level, which means it should be enabled for all environments, and, for example the timestampable annotation is working.   I also tried explicitly adding a test config, and nothing changed. I am wondering if there is another config that I'm forgetting but I couldn't find one.

Comment: How about bundles.php file?

Comment: Great thought, but there is a key in the bundles file:    Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle::class => ['all' => true],